# Is an email forwarder setup in cPanel private?

Tags: email, cpanel, privacy

If I setup an email forwarder in cPanel can someone find the address it forwards to? Can some kind of tracing program be used?

I have a number of low value websites that I don't want associated with each other and don't want to spend $10 each on privacy protection.

Thanks.